# Database tool for Android other than SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new to Android programming and I have made a few simple apps which use SQLite to store user's data. Now I am working on a little more complex app in which I need to implement **many-to-many** relationship among the tables.
[image: database table setup]

So basically, I have three layers (3 Tables) that would be connected to each other and I can't find a good tutorial or any documentation on how to do it. I've spent weeks on researching this. I also looked into realm-database but it's complicated for many-to-many table setup.

So is there any easier solution to this for a beginner? Or is there another tool that I can use to accomplish my task. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example isn't a many to many relationship. It's a one to many, each country can only exist in one continent and each state in only one country.

You can get the structure you want by adding a reference to the parent type's ID.

```
CREATE TABLE continent (
  _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE country (
  _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  continentId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY continentId REFERENCES continent(_id)
)

CREATE TABLE state (
  _id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  countryId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY countryId REFERENCES country(_id)
)
```

To select all the countries on a continent, just ask SQL using the correct ID.

```
SELECT * 
FROM country 
WHERE continentId = ?
```

Or you can join them together.

```
SELECT * 
FROM continent 
  JOIN country ON continent._id = country.continent
  JOIN state ON country._id = state.countryId
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do many-to-may relationships with SQLite. For the example shown you just need some XREF tables. For example (pseudocode):

```
Table CONTINENT(
     ContinentID 
    ,ContinentName
)

Table COUNTRY(
     CountryID
    ,CountryName
)

Table CONTINENT_COUNTRY_XREF (
     Continent_Country_XrefID
    ,ContinentID
    ,CountryID    
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know that I can create multiple tables with SQLite but I am new to Android so I don't know how to connect those tables and retrieve data. Do you have any link to a good tutorial. I can't find a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Ultralite database from SAP. It supports joins as well.

More details here 
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/mobility-platform/blog/2012/08/23/how-to-open-an-ultralite-db-udb

Comment: Thanks for the link, but how do I integrate this with my Android app. Like I said, I am new to this so I don't know much. Any link to a tutorial would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To connect two tables in a many to many relationship, create a third table with three columns. The first column is just a standard is for the primary key. The other two columns are secondary keys into the two original tables. Googling " many to many relationship" will provide more details.